# field_view_value() returns no items in Computed Field

Tags: entities

I am trying to compute the value of a field using the [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module.
I need to get the formatted value of a field [field_get_items()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and [field_view_value()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7).

I think there should be no problems with this procedure as this method seems to be common practice to retreive the field value.
However, I am able to obtain the individual items itself, but the *render array* is not being generated.

`$fields = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $fn_it)` returns an array containing the individual items.
`field_view_value($entity_type, $entity, $fn_it, $v)` returns an array with 0 elements.

```
$fn_it = 'field_autors_it';
$fn_ext = 'field_authors';

$fields_it = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $fn_znes);
$fields_ext = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $fn_ext);

// Render authors if they exist
dpm($fields_it); // < Containing instances' data
if($fields_it && count($fields_it) > 0) {
  foreach($fields_it as $key=>$v) {
      dpm("Item: "); dpm($v); // < Valid item

      $render_array= field_view_value($entity_type, $entity, $fn_it, $v);
      dpm($render_array); // < This results in (Array, 0 elements) 
      $fv = render($render_array);
  }
}
```

*Computed Field* provides several of the variables used above:

```
The variables available to your code include: &$entity_field, $entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, and $items.
```

And the module's example of getting rough field data is even like that:

```
Here's a simple example which sets the computed field's value to the value of the sum of the number fields (field_a and field_b) in a node entity:

$field_a = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, "field_a");
$field_b = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, "field_b");
```

I also tried getting the rough data by field_view_field() - no results either.

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Any idea what I'm missing?

Best, e.